# Set center coordinate for Leaflet-tilelayer-mask layer

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I am working with this Leaflet plugin: [Leaflet-tilelayer-mask](https://github.com/frogcat/leaflet-tilelayer-mask)  and I want to specify the mask center coordinate as opposed to it picking the base map's center coordinate. Tips on how to achieve this?

```
let map = L.map("map", {
    zoom: 16,
    center: [35.9734, 117.7926]
});


// background layer -- color filter plugin
let myTileLayer = L.tileLayer.colorFilter('https://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/pioneer/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', {
    attribution: ''
}).addTo(map);

// mask layer -- tileLayer mask plugin
let mask = L.tileLayer.mask('https://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/pioneer/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', {
    maskSize: 512,
    maxZoom: 18,
    maxNativeZoom: 17
}).addTo(map);


map.on("load", function(e) {
    // mask.setCenter(e.containerPoint);
    mask.setCenter({ lat: 35.9665, lng: 117.8089 }); // this doesn't work

});
```

Comment: If you look at the plugin docs at https://github.com/frogcat/leaflet-tilelayer-mask, you'll se that `.setCenter` method parameters should be in pixels relative to map container.

Comment: @TomazicM that's correct but the mask will move when panning since its position, in pixels, is relative to the map's center and I intend that the mask is at a single exact position everytime. I guess I'll have to set a fixed viewing bounds to the map then.

Comment: I didn't try it, but since `.setCenter` method pertains to `L.tileLayer.mask`, I would say only layer mask will be affected by it. It won't hurt if you try it.

Comment: Sure, I did and work for a first draft of the task at hand. Thank you! @TomazicM . Maybe you post as the solution and I mark as same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two reasons why your code cannot work. If you looks at the plugin docs at https://github.com/frogcat/leaflet-tilelayer-mask, you'll see that `.setCenter` method parameter should be in pixels relative to map container, so you have to use `map.map.latLngToContainerPoint` method to convert geographical coordinates to pixel coordinates.

The second problem is that you are setting map's `load` event processing too late. This event is fired when map's center and zoom are set for the first time: Since in your case this happens at the time of map creation, your event never gets fired.

Code should then look something like this:

```
let map = L.map('map');
.
.
.
map.on('load', function(e) {
  var point = map.latLngToContainerPoint(L.latLng(35.9665, 117.8089));
  mask.setCenter(point);
});

map.setView([35.9734, 117.7926], 16);
```